# Functions: Coordinates of Image Points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

The point $(x,y)$ is on the graph $y = h(x)$. Determine the coordinates of the image point of $(x, y)$ when the graph of $y = h(x)$ is mapped to the graph $y = 2h(-3x) + 5$.

I know the answer is:

$$(x, y) \longrightarrow \left(-\frac{x}{3}, 2y + 5\right)$$

But I don't understand the question nor the answer. Why in the second bracket is it $\frac{x}{-3}$ but for $y$ it is $2y + 5$?

Comment: Read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Note that the transformation $f(x) \to af(x)$ stretches the graph vertically by a factor of $a$.  It is a reflection in the $x$-axis if $a < 0$.  The transformation $f(x) \to f(bx)$, with $b \neq 0$, stretches the graph horizontally by a factor of $1/b$.  It is a reflection in the $y$-axis if $b < 0$.  The transformation $f(x) \to f(x - h)$ shifts the graph of $f(x)$ to the right by $h$ units.  When $h < 0$, it shifts the graph of $f(x)$ to the left by $|h|$ units.  The transformation $f(x) \to f(x) + k$ shifts the graph of $f(x)$ vertically by $k$ units.